# Connection refused: connect, can't connect database mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I can't connect remote database. When I connect my own database on localhost, it connects. What's wrong?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!

    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Java Code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://ipadress:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String query = "SELECT * FROM database";

        System.out.println("Connecting database...");
          try {
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle the error
    }
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
            System.out.println("Database connected!");
            //Uruchamiamy zapytanie do bazy danych
                        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                        while (rs.next()) {

                        }

                        connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
        }
    }
```

I can login to database on PHPMyAdmin, I have no root account, it's my friend's database. I checked if port 3306 is open here: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and it's closed. Where can I open it? In router settings in "port forwarding"? What private IP and type(TCP or UDP) should I set to open this port?

Comment: May be you can share your code?

Comment: Are the  URL and credentials for the remote db mentioned correctly?

Comment: yes, they are
I changed them, because I dont want to share my database adress

Comment: Have you checked the obvious (that mysqld is running on that machine, listening on port 3306)? And the not-so-obvious: is it listening on that network interface (not for example restricted to localhost)?

Comment: I checked it by "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';" and it's on 3306
How to check second thing?

Comment: If you google "jdbc Communications link failure" you'll get ten's of stackoverflow hits on suggestions on how to correct.

Comment: And following @HuguesMoreau, that the port is open externally (e.g., no firewall).

Comment: I did everything, nothing helps, firewall is disabled

Comment: But there's everything good with code? @Hugues Moreau

Comment: @Jkrr Not really, I see that you catch and silently ignore an exception (`// handle the error` in catch block and nothing else). Don't do that, perhaps something bad happens here and your code is oblivious to it. At least print the stack trace and return/break/exit here.

Comment: But I'm asking about problems with code, which may cause "cannot connect to database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apologies if this answer is incomplete, but there is too much that does not fit in comments)

1) Don't ignore exceptions. This is bad : with `// handle the error` and nothing else in your `catch` block, in case of error there, your code will *not report the error*, and will *move on with the execution* (it should exit/break/return, depending on where that piece of code is).

2) I think checking `"SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';"` is not enough. Ask your friend if the database daemon *actually listens* to port 3306 on a network interface that you can reach. MySQL can be configured with networking disabled (`skip-networking`), or enabled but only for local machine (`bind-address=127.0.0.1` or `localhost` -- it should be `bind-address=0.0.0.0` or `bind-address=hostname` or public IP address...).

To check for that yourself, if you are on linux, try with `nc` or `telnet` (install `nc` if you don't have it): `nc remotehost 3306`. If you get "connection refused", the error is definitely not in your java code, but in the server setup.

Comment: "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';" and it's on 3306, I will ask him to do these thing. I updated my question, please check it.

Comment: What I mean is I think checking this is not enough, he needs to check the `my.cnf` config file with the keys I mentioned. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: What about that, port 3306 is closed in my router?

Comment: If it's a home router, port 3306 being closed for inbound connections is normal and will not prevent you from connecting to an external server (outbound connection). Have you fixed point 1, and have you tried installing `nc` and perform the check I recommended?

Comment: I fixed point 1, there's no error. Can I install 'nc' on Linux on VM?

Comment: Yes, or if you are on Windows, try to open a `cmd` shell and then `telnet remoteipaddress 3306`

Comment: 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: *sigh* I don't have Windows, sorry, please [check this](https://kb.ctera.com/article/how-to-open-a-telnet-session-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-os-16.html). And please note we are far past the *programming question*, we are in off-topic territory, your question might get flagged & shot.

Comment: I tried telnet on Linux on VM and there's error: connection refused.

Comment: There! You have your answer. The server does not listen on port 3306 on public address. Check point 2 with your friend.